# Postfix sending mail as root@example instead of root@example.com

Tags: postfix, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to send mails from my server using `postfix` and it works perfectly except for one thing; it sends the mail as `root@example` instead of `root@example.com`.

Here's my config file, what did I miss?

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = example.com
mydomain = example.com
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
virtual_alias_domains = example.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = example.com, localhost.example.com, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 94.23.211.117/24
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
#myorigin = /etc/mailname
myorigin = example.com


# My config
home_mailbox = Maildir/
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

In case you need to take a look at my virtual file and generic file here they are respectively:

Virtual:

```
root@example.com    root
```

Generic:

```
root    root@example.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check `/etc/mailname` and add a line `1.2.3.4 example.com example` to `/etc/hosts`. Possibly your need to uncomment the `myorigin` line in your main.cf config. This should be the most common places, where the FQDN is derived from.

Comment: You were right, I had to change my hosts file from `1.2.3.4 example example` to `1.2.3.4 example.com example`. Thanks!